# Download a file while clicking on href link?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, download, angularjs-ng-click

is there any way I can download a file when I click on a file using `ng-click`? Here is what I have now:

```
<a ng-href="../api/rest/admin/v1/syncsessions/export?fileKey={{syncObject.sourceFiles}}">Download file</a>
```

This seems to work fine. However, the issue is, when I click on the `href`, I get redirected to a page with the url on it. As a result, I want to do something like this:

```
<a ng-click="getExportFiles({{syncObject.sourceFiles}})">Download File</a>
```

Where getExportFiles is defined as so:

```
var baseSyncUrl = "../api/rest/admin/{{path.version}}/syncsessions";
var exportSyncFileReq = {method: "GET", url: baseSyncUrl + "/export", params: {fileKey: ""}, path: {version: "v1"}};

$scope.getExportFiles = function(fileKey) {
    var req = exportSyncFileReq;
    req.params.fileKey = fileKey;
    var data = RESTCaller.getConfig(req);
    data.then(function(result) {
        if(result) {
            return result;
        }
    })
}
```

Contained within result is the link to the file, for example it would be `https://<insertURL>` since `RESTCaller` unwraps my `promise` after calling the `exportSynceFileReq` API defined. The problem is, when i do `ng-click`, nothing happens. The file is not downloaded. If I do

```
<a ng-href="{{getExportFiles(syncObject.sourceFiles)}}">Download File</a>
```

I get an infinite digest loop. Is there a way where I can simply click on a link, call my API, then download the file automatically without redirecting to another page? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a link from the server you can try to use dummy link and click on it:

```
$scope.getExportFiles = function(fileKey) {
    var req = exportSyncFileReq;
    req.params.fileKey = fileKey;
    var data = RESTCaller.getConfig(req);
    data.then(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            //link.download = 'filename.ext';
            link.href = result;
            link.click();
        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT**: If you're looking for native HTML solution, you can also use the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download)

```html
<a href="path" download>Download File</a>
```

the download attribute also support filename.

Comment: This almost works actaully! When I put `link.download = result` I get an error that downloads the file but it unfortunately says "Failed - No file" Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: EDIT: Actually fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me in Chrome but not in IE. There are no errors either. Any ideas why it wouldn't work in IE?

Comment: @BelgoCanadian I think that in IE you nee to add link to DOM so use `document.body.appendChild(link); link.click(); document.body.removeChild(link);`

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to do exactly this with AngularJS before, and I resorted to using the [angular-file-saver](http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) library.

The code below uses your initial `RESTCaller.getConfig(...)` function, but then uses the `$http` provider to fetch the file contents, create a Blob object out of the returned buffer, and then finally call `angular-file-saver`'s `saveAs` function to perform a browser download.

```
$scope.getExportFiles = function(fileKey) {

  // Build the URL we're wanting to fetch
  RESTCaller.getConfig({
    method: "GET",
    url: baseSyncUrl + "/export",
    params: {
      fileKey: fileKey.toString()
    },
    path: { version: "v1" }
  }).then(function(result) {

    // Assuming result is the URL of the download file.
    var fetchUrl = result.toString();

    // Check if the current browser has support for Blob objects
    try { var blobSupport = !!new Blob; } catch (e) {}

    // If there is Blob support, use the angular-file-saver library
    // to download the file
    if (blobSupport) {

      $http
        .get(fetchUrl, {}, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
        .then(function(response) {
          saveAs(new Blob([ response.data ], {
            // You need to specify the file format for the browser
            // to handle the download correctly. Whether this is hard-coded
            // or dynamically returned by your API is up to you.
            type: 'application/octet-stream'
          }), fileKey);
        });

    } else {

      // Use some other method a retrieving the file, whether
      // that be creating an 'A' element in the DOM and triggering
      // the 'click' event, or using $window
      $window.open(fetchUrl);

    }

  });
 };
```

You can find more information on Blob objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob).

You can see some other Blob-related examples in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghinda/fRgbf/).